# How to detect which app is continuously showing "Network Error" toast messages

Tags: toast-notifications

I want to understand (and report the bug) which app is showing the "Network Error" toast notifications in the middle of the screen each time when I unlock the device. Any tips or ideas?

I'm a JS developer, so can utilise any developer tools if necessary.

Device is stock oneplus 5, Android 7.1.1 if that matters.